# KornShell (ksh): info message under read input

Tags: ksh

Using KornShell, I want to ask the user for an input. 
The goal will be to make an info message, which appear under the input request.

My script so far:

```
info_message="test"

read input?"Select script: \n{info_message}"
```

Expected output:

```
Select script: (mouse cursor here)
test
```

Real output:

```
Select script: \ntest
```

**Attention**: The mouse cursor should be remain at the read input and not at the info message below.

KornShell is something new for me, but I am interested in it and would like to get to know it.

Comment: You'll have to spend time learning about terminal sequences (i.e. `ESC[6h;`) and how they manipulate a terminal display. As far as using `\n`, that will never work. Is this really the best use of your time? ;-? If you really, really need/want this (or just want a challenge), you'll find info about terminal sequences by searching here for `[bash] tput cup`. Good luck!

Comment: Okay thanks. It's not that important, I just wanted to know if it's even possible at all. If I have time left, I will certainly study it. :-) @shellter